# What is the shortcut to add multiple fields to a class?

Tags: python, pycharm

Lets, say that I have a such a class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, ...):
```

I need a shortcut to add fields given in constructor definition to my model. So after clicking some fancy keys combinations I expect such result:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, ...):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        more fields...
```

What is the workaround to achieve expected result?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I doubt it is a duplicate. This question is not about how to design a class with long arg list in \_\_init__ method, but rather about how to make automagic in IDE or editor to generate the body of \_\_init__ method.

Comment: @PakUula It may not be identical but I still think it applies, and results in more readable code anyway.